# TeXstudio appears to build stuff I didn't tell it to build?! What gives?

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio on Ubuntu 20.04 with the TeXlive distribution from this year. TeXstudio reports as TeXstudio 2.12.22 (Build: 2.12.22+debian-1build1).

Now for reasons beyond me at times TeXstudio will start building documents with names that appear to be randomly generated. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Messages pane in TeXstudio]

Or as plain text:

```
Process started: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mydocument.tex"

Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hhCMKWs \dump"

Process exited with error(s)

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "HgdqIN".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "UYyUaE".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mgLZrf".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Process exited with error(s)

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "xbSzpJ".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "YqnIyM".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Process exited with error(s)

Process exited with error(s)
```

At the time this happens I only have a single document open.

Does anyone have an idea whether that is supposed to be normal behavior and what it could possibly mean? Strangely enough these messages always show `pdflatex` being used instead of the configured `lualatex`. In the above shown output the first three lines represent me having pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> (Build & View), whereas the other items weren't caused by any conscious action on my part.

Comment: This looks like the equation preview utility of TeXstudio.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ please feel free to write that up as an answer. The term "equation preview utility" alone helps me, because it lets me look for it in the help and on the web, but perhaps you can include some details. I'm not aware that there is any preview _shown_ to me, but indeed I do have equations in that document.